# Aed html currency symbol code

Tags: html

Other currency symbol code is working in safari & other browsers. UAE currency symbol is working in Firefox & Chrome, but it is not working properly in safari browser

Answer (score 4):

Did you try using `hex` notation to display the symbol?

`hex` symbol for AED is `&#x62f;&#x2e;&#x625;`

```html
234.17 <span>&#x62f;&#x2e;&#x625;</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way with **[Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)**:

```js
var number = 244.70;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ar', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'AED'
}).format(number));
```

or use real Arabic digits:

```js
var number = 244.70;

// Arabic in most Arabic speaking countries uses real Arabic digits
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ar-ae', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'AED'
}).format(number));
```